# How to set getline to not get empty string

Tags: c++, string, getline, stringstream

I have for example

```
string s = "      abc        edef";
```

I create `istringstream` with this string.
Is there any way to from `getline` get only `"abc"`and `"edef"` ? Beacouse now I get that empty string between pairs of spaces :/

Comment: Why not just use something like `cin` that separates by whitespace then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `>>` operator to get only whitespace-delimited "words".